# Como conectar o Mariadb com python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb

Amigos, existe alguma forma de conectar o Python 3 com o MariaDB? Além disso, poderiam indicar algum material em inglês ou português?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: MariaDB é só uma implementação do MySQL (afaik), portanto, qualquer documentação que encontrar sobre conectar Python com MySQL deve ser válida. No Google com certeza há várias.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846050/python-3-3-mysql-connector eles explicam a situação...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para se conectar ao MariaDB usando o módulo MySQL Python no seu programa, você tem que importá-lo primeiro, assim como qualquer outro módulo. Para maior clareza e facilidade de uso, importe a classe de conector somente sob o nome **import mysql.connector as mariadb**. Vou usar a classe sob o nome mariadb nos exemplos a seguir.
Em seguida, estabeleça uma conexão de banco de dados com código como **mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='python_user', password='some_pass', database='employees')** , onde você atribui valores reais para usuário, senha e banco de dados. Finalmente, para começar a interagir com o banco de dados e executar consultas, você precisa instanciar o objeto cursor com o código **cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()**. Até agora, seu código inicial deve ser semelhante a este:

## ! / Usr / bin / python

Import mysql.connector como mariadb

Mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect (user = 'python_user', senha = 'some_pass', database = 'employees') Cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor ()

Aqui tem o material completo, de fácil entendimento:  https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

Answer (score 1):

Como o MariaDB é o mesmo core do MySQL, você pode utilizar o mesmo módulo de MySQL para poder acessar o DB.

[Acesse este link e veja](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Answer (score -2):

https://cadernodelaboratorio.com.br/pymysql-integrando-python-com-o-mariadb/

```
import pymysql.cursors

con = pymysql.connect(host='', user='', password='', database='', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with con.cursor() as c:
    sql = "SELECT *FROM *"
    c.execute(sql)
    res = c.fetchone() 
    print(res)
con.close()
```